# Can't customize yii uri

Tags: yii

I'm completely tired to search for solution for my problem. I want to change uri method form get to path in yii. So as it says I uncommented urlmanager but nothing happened and when I try to do domain/controller/action I receive 'No input file specified'.Also I modified my nginx server with  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
} 
So does anybody has any suggestions?

```
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
            ),
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Please refer to [Yii nginx community](http://wiki.nginx.org/Yii).

Comment: I tried these configues but server returns fail when I do reload

Answer (score 0):

resolved. I signed the wrong root path in server configues